# How to get current device Temperature and humidity values in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a flutter app that tracks current device humidity and temperature readings. How can i achieve this and with which package?

Answer (score 0):

you can use environment_sensors package but keep in mind that it only support android platform and that your device have these sensors.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/environment_sensors/versions/0.1.1 package link